# Row counter per Column

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table like so

```
| id | user_id | event_id | created_at |
|----|---------|----------|------------|
| 1  | 5       | 10       | 2015-01-01 |
| 2  | 6       | 7        | 2015-01-02 |
| 3  | 3       | 8        | 2015-01-01 |
| 4  | 5       | 9        | 2015-01-04 |
| 5  | 5       | 10       | 2015-01-02 |
| 6  | 6       | 1        | 2015-01-01 |
```

I want to be able to generate a counter of events per user. So my result would be:

```
| counter | user_id | event_id | created_at |
|---------|---------|----------|------------|
| 1       | 5       | 10       | 2015-01-01 |
| 1       | 6       | 7        | 2015-01-02 |
| 1       | 3       | 8        | 2015-01-01 |
| 2       | 5       | 9        | 2015-01-04 |
| 3       | 5       | 10       | 2015-01-02 |
| 2       | 6       | 1        | 2015-01-01 |
```

Comment: have you tried a group by query? You should show your attempt to solve the problem first.

Comment: Group by won't work. It will give me the total count. Not a counter.

Comment: ok I see. I'm not sure what you want is easily possible using SQL. Might be best to return the raw data and then process it in your application.

Comment: can you explain what the counter counts? in your example user 6 has 2 events, how come the counter is "2" and "3"?

Comment: A running counter of the number of events the user has triggered. 

Say I want to see specifically the list of first 10 events a user triggers, this should make it easy.

Fixed the example.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you then accept the so the question could be closed. Read [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to self join the table and `group by` to replicate `row_number() over..` function available in other RDBMS.

Check this [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RWQG41544) and see second query, to understand how `inner join` works in this case.

```
    select  t1.user_id,
        t1.event_id,
        t1.created_at,
        count(*) as counter
from your_table t1
inner join your_table t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id 
    and t1.id>=t2.id
group by t1.user_id,
         t1.event_id,
         t1.created_at
order by t1.user_id,t1.event_id;
```

Output:

```
 +---------+----------+------------+---------+
| user_id | event_id | created_at | counter |
+---------+----------+------------+---------+
|       3 |        8 | 01-01-2015 |       1 |
|       5 |       10 | 01-01-2015 |       1 |
|       5 |       10 | 02-01-2015 |       3 |
|       5 |        9 | 04-01-2015 |       2 |
|       6 |        1 | 01-01-2015 |       2 |
|       6 |        7 | 02-01-2015 |       1 |
+---------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Sorry.. my example got edited. I fixed it. I'm not sure I follow how your query works.

Comment: Check the updated answer. And check the Rextester demo and see second query to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select counter,
       xx.user_id,
       xx.event_id,
       xx.created_at
  from xx 
  join (select a.id,
               a.user_id,
               count(*) as counter 
          from xx as a 
          join xx as b 
            on a.user_id=b.user_id 
           and b.id<=a.id 
         group by 1,2) as counts 
         on xx.id=counts.id
```

Use a join to generate rows for each id with all the other lower ids for that user below it and count them.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one:

Sub query will help to get this rsult.

```
select  (select count(*) from user_event iue where iue.user_id  == oue.user_id) as counter,
    oue.user_id,
    oue.event_id,
    oue.created_at
from user_event oue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a variable as a table, cross join it with the source table and reset whenever user id changes.

```
SELECT @counter := CASE 
                     WHEN @user = user_id THEN @counter + 1 
                     ELSE 1 
                   END  AS counter, 
       @user := user_id AS user_id, 
       event_id, 
       created_at 
FROM   your_table m, 
       (SELECT @counter := 0, 
               @user := '') AS t 
ORDER  BY user_id;
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/YESN81009)